# How do I use ranged weapons?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I feel like an idiot. I have the starting crossbow equipped, but my character, instead of using ranged attack, runs up to the enemy to melee them instead with her boots. How exactly should I get her to use the crossbow instead?

Comment: I would have suggested to go through the tutorial first haha

Comment: @jonleech pff.. tutorials.. who needs them... :P.

Comment: haha I have been to the party late but yea dungeons is an awesome game!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use a ranged weapon, you need to right click on the arrows you want to use, the arrow will then show up in the yellow box to the right of your character portrait, and then right click on the enemy you want to fire at.